Catalog generation in wCDM cosmology with nbodykit
I am using nbodykit for cosmological simulations and have successfully run simulations using the LambdaCDM cosmology. However, when I switch to wCDM cosmology, I encounter issues.
Here is a simplified example of the code that works with LambdaCDM:
redshift = 0.55
cosmo = cosmology.Planck15
Plin = cosmology.LinearPower(cosmo, redshift, transfer='EisensteinHu')
b1 = 2.0

cat = LogNormalCatalog(Plin=Plin, nbar=3e-3, BoxSize=50., Nmesh=256, bias=b1, seed=42)

The above code works perfectly fine. However, when I try to use wCDM cosmology:
cosmo_astropy = wCDM(H0=70, Om0=0.3, Ode0=0.7, w0=-0.9, Ob0=0.05)

cosmo = cosmology.Cosmology.from_astropy(cosmo_astropy)

redshift = 0.55
Plin = cosmology.LinearPower(cosmo, redshift, transfer='EisensteinHu')
b1 = 2.0

cat = LogNormalCatalog(Plin=Plin, nbar=3e-3, BoxSize=50., Nmesh=256, bias=b1, seed=42)

I encounter the following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ClassBadValueError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[46], line 6
      3 cosmo = cosmology.Cosmology.from_astropy(cosmo_astropy)
      5 redshif = 0.55
----> 6 Plin = cosmology.LinearPower(cosmo, redshift, transfer='EisensteinHu')
      7 b1 = 2.0
      9 cat = LogNormalCatalog(Plin=Plin, nbar=3e-3, BoxSize=50., Nmesh=256, bias=b1, seed=42)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/nbodykit-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbodykit/cosmology/power/linear.py:45, in LinearPower.__init__(self, cosmo, redshift, transfer)
     42 self.cosmo = cosmo.clone()
     44 # set sigma8 to the cosmology value
---> 45 self._sigma8 = self.cosmo.sigma8
     47 # setup the transfers
     48 if transfer not in transfers.available:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/nbodykit-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbodykit/cosmology/cosmology.py:243, in Cosmology.sigma8(self)
    233 @property
    234 def sigma8(self):
    235     """
    236     The amplitude of matter fluctuations at :math:`z=0` in a sphere
    237     of radius :math:`r = 8 \ h^{-1}\mathrm{Mpc}`.
   (...)
    241     achieve the desired ``sigma8``.
    242     """
--> 243     return self.Spectra.sigma8

File ~/anaconda3/envs/nbodykit-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbodykit/cosmology/cosmology.py:217, in Cosmology.__getattr__(self, name)
    215     iface = self.dro_dict[name]
    216     if iface not in self.delegates:
--> 217         self.delegates[iface] = iface(self.engine)
    218     return self.delegates[iface]
    220 # resolving a name from the delegates : c.Om0 => c.Background.Om0

File classylss/binding.pyx:1189, in classylss.binding.Spectra.__init__()

File classylss/binding.pyx:281, in classylss.binding.ClassEngine.compute()

ClassBadValueError: background_init(L:657) :error in background_solve(ppr,pba);
=>background_solve(L:1551) :error in background_initial_conditions(ppr,pba,pvecback,pvecback_integration);
=>background_initial_conditions(L:2038) :condition (fabs(pvecback[pba->index_bg_Omega_r]-1.) > ppr->tol_initial_Omega_r) is true; Omega_r = 0.000000e+00, not close enough to 1. Decrease a_ini_over_a_today_default in order to start from radiation domination.

Could anyone help me understand why the wCDM cosmology setup is failing while LambdaCDM works fine? Is there a special configuration required for wCDM in nbodykit?
Additionally, if I have a discrete power spectrum generated by other programs, can I perform a spline interpolation and set Plin=spline, defining cosmo and redshift separately while still using cosmo=wCDM? I encounter the same error when attempting this, but I am not sure if it is a valid approach.
Thank you!

The problem seems to be that the cosmo object returned by cosmology.Cosmology.from_astropy(cosmo_astropy) does not match what cosmology.LinearPower is expecting. It looks possible that this cosmo object lacks a sigma8 attribute or lacks the data required by the sigma8 method.

I’m voting to close this question because checking code is off-topic.

Per the [tag:computational-physics] tag info, questions about specific packages should be asked at the relevant user page (the ReadTheDocs page suggests going to their github page)
